# Can't connect to server Resolve/ConnectTimeout error

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey

I have a common problem on Android only that I don't know how to reproduce on demand. It happens on Android 7, 9 and 11. Internet permission is enable and accepted on the app.

When we open the application, a call to my server is done.

```
function TXXVersion.GetVersion : IXXVersion;
var
  LVSPortType : VersionServicePortType; // generate from wsdl
  LIdURI: TIdURI;
begin
  Result := nil;

  if Assigned(FWebServiceHelper.PrepareCall(VersionServicePortType, LVSPortType, false)) then
  begin
    LIdURI := TIdURI.Create('https://my-backend.test.com');
    try
      Result := ParseVersion(LVSPortType.GetVersion, LIdURI.Host);
    finally
      LIdURI.Free;
    end;
  end;
end;
```

I got the system error message :

```
An unexpected error (EIdResolveError) occurred with message:
Error resolving Address my-backend.test.com:
No address associated with hostname (7)
```

If I try

- to ping `my-backend.test.com` or access with a webbrowser it's ok
- try several times I'll end up with a EIdConnectTimeout

If I reboot my phone, it works until 2-3 days and then I will get this error again.

I never got this problem on other plateform, that's only on Android. I see nothing other with adb.

Comment: Looks like DNS issue to me.

Comment: Is your phone connected via WIFI or mobile Internet?

Comment: I got same result in wifi or mobile internet

Comment: `EIdResolveError` is raised by Indy's `TIdStack.HostByName()` when the underlying OS fails to resolve a hostname into an IP. On Android, `TIdStackVCLPosix.HostByName()` calls the Posix `getaddrinfo()` function, which in this case is returning error `EAI_NODATA`. So, this is definitely an OS DNS issue.